# Find that the pattern does not exist in the string Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm new in Groovy coding (
I have the stings that hold the ip address and GUID. Sometime the GUID is empty.

```
For example: 
139.14.8.162    b38e34ab-32ad-46b3-961c-17762c1c2957
139.268.15.201
```

How in Groovy I can get the ip address from the line where the GUID does not exist? In my example I need to skip the line with 139.14.8.162 get the 139.268.15.201

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the IP addresses from lines which do not have a GUID...

1. Split the `String` into lines.
2. Use a regular expression to find the lines which only have an IP

### Example code

```
// Sample data
def data = '''139.14.8.162    b38e34ab-32ad-46b3-961c-17762c1c2957
139.268.15.201
139.269.14.201
139.15.9.162    961c-32ad-46b3-961c-17762c1c2957'''

def ipAddresses = data.split(/\n/).findAll { it ==~ /^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ }

// Assertion showing it works.
assert ipAddresses == ['139.268.15.201', '139.269.14.201']
```

### How it works

First, `data.split(/\n/)` returns a `List` containing each line in the `String`. Finally, `findAll { it ==~ /^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ }` traverses the `List` and returns all of the entries which match the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
def data = '''139.14.8.162    b38e34ab-32ad-46b3-961c-17762c1c2957
139.268.15.20
139.269.14.201
139.15.9.162    961c-32ad-46b3-961c-17762c1c2957'''

// Poor man's solution if you are sure that you would get IPv4 strings
data.readLines().findAll { it.trim().size() <= 15 }

// A little explicit from above solution
data.readLines().findAll { it.tokenize(/./)[3].trim().size() <= 3 }

// Extensions to previous answers
data.readLines()*.split().findResults { it.size() == 1 ? it[0] : null }

// BDKosher's approach using readLines()
data.readLines()*.split().findAll { it.size() == 1 }.flatten()

// UPDATE: And yes I totally missed JDK 8 Stream implementation
data.readLines()
    .stream()
    .filter { it.trim().size() <= 15 }
    .map { it.trim() }
    .collect()
```

From the frequency of answers you would imagine there are more than one ways to find a solution to a problem in Groovy. Hence the name. :)

I am quite sure you would enjoy the journey.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions to parse the contents.

If you split each line of the config, it should produce arrays with either one or two elements: a one element array for the lines with only an IP, a two element array if the line has both an IP and GUID.

Then it's a matter of grabbing only the one-element arrays.

```
data.split(/\n/)                       // convert String into List of Strings (if needed)
    .collect { line -> line.split() }  // transform each line into an array
    .findAll { it.size() == 1 }        // select the lines that only had IPs
    .flatten()                         // flatten each 1-element array to get a list of IPs
```